# How to show a set of animation multiple times in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->label, "geometry");

    startAnimation();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete m_animation;
}

void MainWindow::startAnimation()
{
    m_animation->setDuration(3000);

    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.25, QRect(200, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.5, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.75, QRect(200, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(1, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));

    m_animation->start();
}
```

I want to show the animation done in `startAnimation` function multiple times, right now it shows only two times. I tried using `QSequential` but that is also not working. I also tried to connect this function with a thread but when I am creating object of thread class, it is showing unresolved symbol error.

Comment: If you need apply a few animation at one time then you need QParallelAnimationGroup, if you want apply animation one after another you need QSequentialAnimationGroup. What exactly you need?

Comment: I dont want to show two animation at the same time, so QSequential wont help me. i want to show above animation multiple times. As you can see it will move an object from (50, 50) to (200, 50), here in this code it will be done twice. I want this animation to be continuous..

Comment: I think Threading will help me, i will put the above code in a while loop in a thread function so it wont stuck and show animation continuously. But i am not sure it will work because when i put the above code in a fuction and called that two times it still animate only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [loopCount](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractanimation.html#loopCount-prop) property.

```
void MainWindow::startAnimation()
{
    m_animation->setLoopCount(10);
    m_animation->setDuration(3000);

    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.25, QRect(200, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.5, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.75, QRect(200, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(1, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));

    m_animation->start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need thread here. All what you need is `QSequentialAnimationGroup` (as I said earlier). For example:

```
int numberOfLoops = 3;
QSequentialAnimationGroup *group = new QSequentialAnimationGroup(this);
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; ++i)
{
    QPropertyAnimation *m_animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "geometry");
    m_animation->setDuration(3000);
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.25, QRect(200, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.5, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.75, QRect(200, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(1, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    group->addAnimation(m_animation);
}
group->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

But I still think that you code now is a little wrong for my approach, so final code is:

```
//type 3 and animation will repeat 3 time, type 10 and it will repeat 10 and so on
int numberOfLoops = 5;
QSequentialAnimationGroup *group = new QSequentialAnimationGroup(this);
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; ++i)
{
    QPropertyAnimation *m_animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "geometry");
    m_animation->setDuration(1500);
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(0.5, QRect(200, 50, 128, 128));
    m_animation->setKeyValueAt(1, QRect(50, 50, 128, 128));
    group->addAnimation(m_animation);
}
group->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

Also don't think that this code produce memory leaks, no! As you can see, I added `QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped` flag which means that all your created `QPropertyAnimation` objects will be destroyed too(when animation will be stoped)! To prove that you can add one line and run app, you will see that all objects will be deleted (but it is just a proof, you don't need do this in `release` app for example):

```
//...
    group->addAnimation(m_animation);
    connect(m_animation,&QPropertyAnimation::destroyed,[](){qDebug()<< "m_animation destroyed";});
//...
```

But I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.

Comment: Not working for me, show "application has stoped working".. how can i send you my code(main.cpp, mainwindow.h and mainwindow,cpp)

Comment: @danishansari I did this in mainwindow.cpp(in constructor), you don't need send code, just edit your question (press Edit) add your current code and tell me in comment that it was done, I will try to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: i also tried doing the same in mainwindow.cpp constructor, the program build successfully but showing runtime error.